# Hide Content Editor webpart title

Tags: 2013, web-part, content-editor-web-part

I have a Custom Page Layout and I have placed a Content Editor Webpart to display some introductory text. I want to hide the title as there was this chrome type property in webpart which appears blank and cant set it to none.

If I remove the title text it appears as UNTITLED. now what to do?

Comment: didn't got you. Why Chrome type none is not helping you??

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what you are describing?

Comment: There's a link to a screenshot in the comments to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If the chrome type does not help you, you can just add a blank space as title. Just tried it out and it works. It's a ugly way to do it, but it works.

Comment: It is not showing properties of Chrome Type..just the heading "Chrome Type" and under that there are no options..this is weird.

Comment: It's really weird. Are the web part modified in any way? Does the options show on the CEWP in any other site collection?

Comment: Please attach a screenshot

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/rma963we3/

Comment: Looks like you are using a custom masterpage / css.. when you are editing the webpart, use F12 developer tools where the dropdown should be, and see if there's any missing element or so.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/wmqfgs5zr/

Comment: user19952 you are right..when i changed my custom masterpage to seattle (default) I got the option back. so how to figure out what is causing this annoying problem?

Comment: F12 developer tools is your best friend. :) See if there is any CSS that accidentally hides the drop down menu. It's all i can think of.. Or you just add a blank space as title.

Comment: its the div of usercontrolgroup

Comment: i am new to this and learning..will figure out but can u tell me is there any problem as per the image? http://postimg.org/image/57dr6cf3n/

Comment: I'm afraid i can't help you out as i just guessed what could have been the cause, if you got a custom masterpage with custom css, it's where you should investigate. But still, if you don't wanna put down anymore time into it, just add a blank space as title.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do programmatically, put `FrameType` as `None` in webpart properties, it will help.

Comment: FYI for SPO users landing on this page, this option does not seem to exist in webpart properties for SPO sites.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the web part and set "Chrome type" to "None".
http://www.isacantx.org/SharePointTraining/TrainingPages/HideWebPartTitle.html

If it does not work or if you wanna do grammatically, then in the     `Page_Load()` of the webpart, add below code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

((System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart)(sender)).ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;

}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, but if you simply change the drop down under "`appearance`" to "`none"`, click **OK** and then save the page, it will then disappear.

Comment: worked for me and by far the easiest answer

Answer (score -1):

You can always hide that html element with CSS